# Scala project-wide static instructions

Tags: scala, static, execution

I'm using a Java lib within my Scala project. I want to call a specific static method `adjustLib` of that lib as early as possible and for *every* possible starting point of an execution (e.g. before runing the "main" `App` and before executing tests) to achieve the desired behaviour.

One solution would be to place this statement at the very top of each class, that might be executed (applies for all classes extending `App` and for all tests).
However, if someone implements a new, executable class but forgets `adjustLib`, things might get weird.

Is there any chance to define an object or something similar, that executes this `adjustLib` statement in a "static" manner *every* time *anything* in the given project is executed?

Comment: Putting aside the fact that this is a code smell (this basically means that you have a global which might works funny if someone start 2 instances of their app at once, don't release resources once something is done etc), you can simply require some instance in order to run your code (take it as argument in constructor or method) and make that instance call this method in its constructor.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the downside of my idea! After posting the question, actually comparable questions came to my mind regarding concurrent execution...